# Why is the field name incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a form in which a grouped `select` list.

```
= f.grouped_collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :categories, :title, :id, :title, { label: 'Category', prompt: '---' }
```

The form is wrapped in `bootstrap_form_for`.

If submit the form without selecting a category, this error will appear:

> {category":["translation missing: ru.activerecord.errors.models.exercise.attributes.category.required","translation missing: ru.activerecord.errors.models.exercise.attributes.category.blank"]}

Why `category`, not `category_id`? I can't replace `category_id` to `category`...

The problem is that validation of fields in this case doesn't work. The definition follows the field name. And the name in the hash is different.

Comment: That's just how I18n works... it gives the name of the required related Category. Just add the required translation and you see the proper error message.

Comment: @bo-oz But in this case the marking (validation) doesn't work...

Comment: That's probably due to the fact you forgot to whitelist the variables in your controller action. Did you add: `category_ids: []`?

Comment: @bo-oz I don't understand how this is related? I wrote above that the field is named `category_id`. But I18n sends `category`. If leave the field empty validation doesn't work.

Comment: I don;t understand what you mean... could you please update with your controller code and the code for the Exercise model?

Comment: @bo-oz I have a form. The form is wrapped in: `bootstrap_form_for`. In this form there is this: `= f.grouped_collection_select :category_id, # ...`. I leave this field empty. I'm sending the form. I get the error text in: `= post.errors.to_json`. But I'm not getting validation at the field. I don't know how else to explain.

Comment: You see the error right? It’s just not translated. Make sure you update the locale file with a translated error message, so that rails knows what you would like to show.

Comment: @bo-oz I did not write about the translation. I wrote that the messages are not displayed in the field ...